# How to verify a downloaded file is real image?

Tags: python, http

For example,I use vim to create a test.jpg file in my server, and `http://www.somedomain.com/test.jpg` could be visit and return 200 http response code but in fact, this 'test.jpg' is not a real image file and it doesn't show anything when opened.

How to judge that was not a correct image file by python?

Comment: How do you, the human, judge that it is not a "correct" image file?  Is it not a valid JPEG file, or is it simply a valid JPEG that shows a blank rectangle?

Comment: I have found out.https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html .this model can return file style.

Answer (score 0):

give [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) a try.
the libraries are used to examine the actual file, regardless of file extensions and tells you what they are.